# Hosting Two Website Under one Web App - Azure Services

Tags: linux, windows, azure

I want to deploy multiple websites on a single azure website. I have tried to deploy multiple websites on the Windows environment and it works fine.

Now, I am trying to deploy same for Linux environment but i can't seem to find my way out.
On the Windows, Azure Web Apps have a configuration page for “path mappings”, they allow you to specify what sub-directories contain a standalone application, and you can map a URL to them.

[image]

On the Linux Environment, there is no configuration page for “Virtual Applications and Directories”. It only shows **Mount storage (Preview)**.

I would like to know if there is any easy way to configure virtual applications and directories on Azure for linux environment

I want to have my urls as **example.com** and **example.com/api**

**example.com/api** is a child project to **example.com**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The current webapp under linux does not support virtual applications.**

*Relevant information*

Virtual directory is IIS concept basically. we can't create virtual directory for Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212842/is-it-possible-to-create-a-virtual-directory-in-linux.

Hard link will help us to create a virtual directory in Linux https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-hard-links-with-ln-command/.

Common linux virtual directories are http://www.emblogic.com/blog/02/common-linux-virtual-directories/

Azure app services in windows, can support virtual application because of `IIS` can handler mappings and virtual applications and directories.

[image]

Azure webapp in linux, I'm not sure whether kestrel supports virtual applications and directories, at least not currently in azure web app products.

If you have more questions about azure web app, [you can raise a support ticket on portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). You can also [put forward your ideas and suggestions in the feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps), and optimize the product together with Microsoft official.