# Azure linux app service: Is it possible to publish two API projects in same app service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

We have set up an Azure Linux app service (API) and want to deploy two API projects (.Net Core) in the same app service. Is it possible in Linux based app service?

Comment: If you have any questions, you can raise a support ticket for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.

**You can refer to the answer in the post below.**

[Hosting Two Website Under one Web App - Azure Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986942/hosting-two-website-under-one-web-app-azure-services/64021829#64021829)

IIS can handler mappings and virtual applications and directories, you can't use virtual applications and directories in linux.

If you have more questions about azure web app, you can [raise a support ticket on portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). You can also [put forward your ideas and suggestions in the feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps), and optimize the product together with Microsoft official.