# Could you please advise how to resolve the issue with URL rewrite rules for azure web app?

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have an MVC dot net application (multi-tenant platform) deployed on Azure Web App.
I have configured two tenants: tenant1 and tenant2, with their URLs:

1. primer-test.azurewebsites.net/tenant1 and
2. primer-test.azurewebsites.net/tenant2

Both of them are accessible from IE, Safari etc. I purchased two domains on GoDaddy:

1. domain1.com
2. domain2.com

and I would like to configure the **rewrite** rules for them so whenever someone types in his browser either [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) or domain1.com, the content of primer-test.azurewebsites.net/tenant1 should be presented. Similarly, for the domain2.

I have attached these two custom domains to my web app, with no problem. I wrote the rewrite rules, but they seem to don't work as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="domain1.com" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?domain1.com" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/tenant1/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="\tenant1\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="domain2.com" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?domain2.com" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/tenant2/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="\tenant2\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\kobsq.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks very much!

Comment: My answer should help you very well. If you need help, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, from the URL you provided, I can see that `primer-test.azurewebsites.net` is the webapp you created and used. `tenant1` and `tenant2` should be `virtual applications` in webapp.

**Concept:**
[`Virtual application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#windows-apps-uncontainerized)

**Related Posts:**

[1. How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149)

[2. Hosting Two Website Under one Web App - Azure Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986942/hosting-two-website-under-one-web-app-azure-services/64021829#64021829)

**Correct use process and test steps:**

*Step 1.*

Preparation work, create a main application of the .net framework (use web.config in the project for the purpose of configuring rewrite.

[image]

Configure in portal.

[image]

Create folder under site path and  deploy virtual app by zip.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Test it without  rewrite settings.

[image]

Step 2. Modify `web.config` file in `RewriteTest` project.

[image]

Step 3. Create custom domain to  test.

[image]

Step 4. Test result. Fulfill your needs.

[image]