# How to publish two .net websites on one Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots, publishing-site

I have two web apps hosted on Windows Azure VM -> IIS with the following names

- MyWeb.com  (Front end for Users- Javascript)
- api.MyWeb.com  (backend for Admins  - .net core app)

Question:

1. Can I publish these two apps into one Azure WebApp? OR do I need to provision two separate Azure WebApps and publish them separately?
2. Where to manage connection string etc?

Note: Both are tied up with the one Public IP e.g (1.2.3.4).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this solves your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986942/hosting-two-website-under-one-web-app-azure-services

Comment: i would deploy fronted to azure static websites and api to app service

Comment: Thanks, Vova for the reply. Sounds like a good idea. 
How about Single Public IP mapping with both (Static and API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, your Front end webapp don't need connection string. So you can set your backend web app as main site. And you can manage

[image]

[image]

So you can deploy your front end in virtual application. You can check my answer in link which NebulaBC's comment for you.

**Related Post:**

[1. How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982446/how-to-deploy-a-flaskreact-application-to-azure-web-service/63985149#63985149)

[2. React.js - How to deploy client and server independently or together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997169/react-js-how-to-deploy-client-and-server-independently-or-together/64020730#64020730)

Comment: Thanks Jason Pan for getting back. How about mapping of one public IP for both? Ref to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67714626/how-to-map-two-azure-apps-with-one-public-ip