# How to map Two azure apps with one public ip?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have two different web apps hosted on one Azure web app service.

Here are two different directories.

http://menuapp.azurewebsites.net/MainSite

http://menuapp.azurewebsites.net/AdminPanel

How I can map them to one public IP? example below

**MyMenu.com**

**adminPanel.MyMenu.com**

Comment: what you want is to map multiple domains to one website ? you could use front door to configure that or application gateway. it will require you create cname entries in your dns

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I am looking for 

MyMune.com should go to /MainSite

and AdminPanel.MyManue.com should go to /AdminPanel

Comment: Yeah have a look at front door and or ap gateway. they support both routing rules. Front door is probably what you want in the first place. or maybe you could create two webapps ?

Comment: I don't wana create two apps due to double cost issue.

Comment: You can add a `rewrite rule` in ` web.config` to achieve it, but you will find that you can visit `http://menuapp.azurewebsites.net/AdminPanel` after using the `adminPanel.MyMenu.com` URL, but the browser URL is still the original one. It is not `adminPanel.MyMenu.com` when you visit.

Comment: If you're using the same app service plan, the cost won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            
            <rule name="mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(admin.mydevapp.nl)$" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydevapp.nl/app2" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## PRIVIOUS

You can use rewrite in web.config.

**My Sample（After 12 hours, the URL expired）:**

Main site url():  http://mydevapp.nl/

virtual app site url:  http://mydevapp.nl/app2

## Gif

1. Visit main site , webapp1

   [image]
2. Visit virtual application site , webapp2

   [image]
3. My structure of webapp.

   [image]

   *my config:*

   [image]

   [image]
4. Add `web.config` like below.

   [image]
5. Result.

   [image]

Comment: wow, wonderful. thanks a lot Jason. Please paste the redirect code snippet (what you shown in the example above).

Comment: @Tariq I have updated my answer, have a nice day. ^-^