how to give back camera access in blazor webassembly
I Developed web application using blazor web assembly, asp.net core, and JavaScript functions,  as of now I gave front camera access , now I want to give a back camera access also.
Steps along with code regarding the back camera in blazor web assembly.

I used Android 14 for testing, and I found that the camera permissions are not differentiated by front and back, so you can try to use the sample code below to check it out.
My Test Link (Will Delete Soon)
https://blazorapp320240722150954.azurewebsites.net/
My Test Code

1. Create a camera.js under wwwroot folder.
async function startCamera(facingMode) {
    const constraints = {
        video: {
            facingMode: facingMode
        }
    };

    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        const videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
        videoElement.srcObject = stream;
        videoElement.play();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error accessing camera: ", error);
    }
}

function startFrontCamera() {
    startCamera("user");
}

function startBackCamera() {
    startCamera("environment");
}

2. Import camera.js in Index.html.

3. Create a Camera.razor file.
@page "/camera"

<button @onclick="StartFrontCamera">Front-facing camera</button>
<button @onclick="StartBackCamera">Rear camera</button>

<video id="video" width="600" height="400" autoplay></video>

@code {
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

    private async Task StartFrontCamera()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("startFrontCamera");
    }

    private async Task StartBackCamera()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("startBackCamera");
    }
}


Thankyou so much for this. can you please help how to host my application free in azure

Hi @AditiJaiswal Ok, please wait.

@AditiJaiswal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net80&pivots=development-environment-vs

I have created three Blazor projects within a single folder and now I want to publish those applications free. How can I do this?

Hi @AditiJaiswal https://stackoverflow.com/a/67714470/7687666  Please check the virtual application feature in azure web app.
