# how to deploy multiple .net core application in single linux based azure app service

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, azure-app-service-plans

I want to deploy multiple .net core API application in single linux based azure app service. I can't find any documentation for that. Can any one give any suggestion or idea how to achieve that.

I have thing one option but don't know is it possible or not? Can I mount azure blob storage space in configuration/ Path mapping in app service and run application from their? is it possible or any other proper way. Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, It is possible to deploy multiple Applications to single Ap service. You need to add the Virtual Paths in Portal => Configuration section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible.

**You can refer to the answer in the post below.**

[Hosting Two Website Under one Web App - Azure Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986942/hosting-two-website-under-one-web-app-azure-services/64021829#64021829)

IIS can handler mappings and virtual applications and directories, you can't use virtual applications and directories in linux.

If you have more questions about azure web app, you can [raise a support ticket on portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). You can also [put forward your ideas and suggestions in the feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/b09330d1-c625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c), and optimize the product together with Microsoft official.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I solved this using creating multiple App services under same service plan, so there is no additional cost and I can achieve what I need. than you for your answer